# calling a web service and get the response to a variable(String) using nodejs. and return that string in ibm cloud functions

Tags: node.js, ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, watson-conversation

I create an ibm cloud function. I am using nodejs as my coding language. once i entered the following few lines in the editor and invoke it.

```
function main() {
   return { message:'response from server' };
}
```

Then i got the 'response from server' as the result.(successful)

As like that I want to call an external web service and get that response(String) instead of this hard-coded response. So I used the below lines for that

```
 const request = require('request-promise');

 function web(){
     return request("https://58a78829.ngrok.io/webhook/testRequest")
     .then(function(response){
     return Promise.resolve(JSON.parse(response)); 
     });
 }

 function main(){
    var y;
    web().then(function(result){
    y=result;
    console.log(y);
    });    

    return { message: y };
 }
```

once I invoke the above code I get nothing as result or log. no value is assign to variable y.

I am not sure whether we can assign the value which return from a method to a variable in nodejs8.

Could any one please help me to solve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use `async` `await` feature of javascript for that. After writing the same code with async await your code will look something like below.

```
const request = require('request-promise');

async function web(){
    const res = await request("https://58a78829.ngrok.io/webhook/testRequest");
    return res;
}

async function main(){    
   const x = await web();
   console.log('x: ', x);
   return { message: x };
}
```

Comment: it did not worked. I got the response as follows                                                                                  Results:
{
  "error": {}
}
Logs:
[]

Comment: I feel that IBM is not supporting some modules required by nodejs.

Comment: Sorry just forgot to add await before the request and I think your response is already in JSON format no need to parse it. Try the updated code.

Comment: Thank you so much. you saved me.